# Verb position in a phrase

Tags: phrases, verbs

I have a question about where would it be best to place the **verb (in bold)** on the phrases below:

P1: To me, It is unthinkable how large the impact of her work **is** for the progress of science and humanity.

P2: To me, It is unthinkable how large **is** the impact of her work for the progress of science and humanity

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Both are fine, a mere difference in style, but I don't think you really want to use *unthinkable* there, do you?

Comment: Thanks @Robusto. Maybe _unimaginable_ instead of _unthinkable_ would be better?

Comment: Sure. Or you could just say "It is difficult to imagine how large ... " Lotta ways to say this.

Comment: Grammatically, P1 is more correct. P2 shows interrogative order: *How large is the impact of her work...?*, and this order should be lost when the question is embedded.

Comment: @Gustavson: No, it's not grammatically more correct. It's just a different way of saying the same thing, a stylistic variation for emphasis or just because you don't want to always say the same thing the same way.